# Problems with jQuery slider and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-slider

I'm trying to make my first jQuery slider, and I have this code:

```
$("#str").keyup(function(event) {
var data=$("#str").val();
if (data.length>0) 
{
 var intdata=SpecialRound(parseFloat(data));
 if (intdata>=0 && intdata<=20) 
 {
  $("#str_slider").slider("option", "value", data);
 }
 else
 {
  if (intdata<0) 
  {
   $("#str").val("0");
   $("#str_slider").slider("option", "value", "0");
  }
  if (intdata>20) 
  {
   $("#str").val("20");
   $("#str_slider").slider("option", "value", "20");
  }
 }
}
});
```

Although, I have a problem. When I write something in the input with the ID #str, nothing happens. Though, the sliders works perfect.
You can test att http://vpopulus.tk/damage

EDIT: I basicly want to make so when you edit the input, the slider is changed too.

Comment: Oh, that is just a function I use to round to two decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your selector `$('#str')` is the problem, because your input has no ID #str but just a name attribute with value "str". The correct selector would be `$('input[name="str"]')`

**EDIT:**
The actual problem is this SpecialRound function because you're using a not-existing function "round()" there. Use this instead:

```
//Special round
function SpecialRound(f) {
   return Math.round(f*100) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mixed some old code with the new one. But you can see at about row 232 that I have ID.

Comment: Ok, didn't see the second input, sorry. Your specialRound() function is the problem, you're using `round()` there, but it is actually `Math.round()`.

Comment: Ah, you didn't put your code (that one binding the event listener to the keyup event) into your onReady event listener, so that it would be executed when the DOM is ready for that kind of action. Now jQuery tries to bind the event listener to an input that isn't yet present the time your code is executed. Understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

if i were you i'd use the change event instead of keyup

for example:

```
$( "#str" ).change(function() {
    var val = this.val(); // you can do your rounding here then...
    $("#str_slider").slider( "value", val );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your testpage, you have at line 54 in SpecialRound

```
var r=round(f*100)/100;
```

that should be

```
var r=Math.round(f*100)/100;
```